# How to extract page containing image in a pdf with python?

Tags: python, image, pdf

I have 4000 scanned documents as pdf's. Each pdf contains a kyc form that i want to extract .Each pdf has 40 pages.What techniques can we use to get the page number of image ,since i can extract the page using pdf2image provided i have page number.

[image]

[image]

The kyc form will be similar and there will be images as posted. I have blurred the image but it will be of better quality

Comment: Have you tried https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2018/09/17/opencv-ocr-and-text-recognition-with-tesseract/ ?

Comment: Would be helpful if you uploaded an anonymized example of the PDFs that you are looking to process. Are you extracting all images? Is any of the form structure retained, or are you also seeking to OCR the extracted images?

Comment: I have added just the content page for a pdf. The problem is this kyc application form is not at same page for all the pdfs.

Answer (score 1):

This is a simplistic approach that scans all bookmarks to find the matching object and then scans each page until it matches the same object. Possibly not the most elegant approach, but should get the job done.

```
from PyPDF2 import PdfFileReader
reader = PdfFileReader('D:\\Downloads\Sample.pdf')

# Scan outlines for bookmark containing KYC
outlines = reader.outlines
print(outlines)
for bookmark in outlines:
    print(bookmark['/Title'])
    print(bookmark['/Page'])
    if bookmark['/Title'] == 'KYC':
        mypage = bookmark['/Page']

# Scan page looking for the matching object        
print(reader.getNumPages())
for x in range(0, reader.getNumPages()): 
    apage = reader.getPage(x)
    print(apage)
    if apage == mypage:
        print('Eureka on page', x + 1)
```

Comment: thanks for the aprroach, but another issue is atleast half of the dont have bookmarks. I am uploading similar kyc form

Comment: If the form is purely image based then you will need to process each page and image using something like 'pyocr' checking for the 'Know Your Client (KYC)' marker. If the same text is extractable (i.e. you can select it when viewing in an PDF reader) then you can search for this directly. Sorry, but if the bookmarks, or some other meta data marker is not consistently used, your options are limited.